# How to filter a column that starts with a given string using sql parameters and still be able to fully take advantage of an index on that column?

Tags: c#, sql-server, indexing

Let's say I have a table with the following definition

```
CREATE TABLE Person (
    ...
    FirstName NVARCHAR(255),
    ...
);

CREATE INDEX IX_FirstName ON Person (FirstName);
```

If I want to get all persons with first name that starts with "Foo" I can wrote the following query :

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE FirstName LIKE "Foo%"
```

The following query is very fast. SQL Server is able to do an index seek on IX_FirstName.

However, because the search term come directly from user input, I have decided to use SQL value parameters :

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Person WHERE FirstName LIKE Concat(@searchterm,'%')"; 
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@searchterm", "Foo")
```

This is (I think) the equivalent of this :

```
DECLARE @searchterm NVARCHAR(255)
SET @searchterm = 'Foo'
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE FirstName LIKE Concat(@searchterm,'%')
```

This result in a index scan (which is slow).
AFAIK because parameter value is not a part of the query, SQL Server is not able to perform parameter sniffing. The search term could be '%Foo%', which make it impossible to use index.

I have also tried the following alternative but it does not help (index scan is used).

```
SELECT * FROM Person WHERE CHARINDEX(@searchterm, DocumentName) = 1
```

Comment: And don't use `AddWithValue`, specify the data type on your `SqlParameter`.

Comment: @SeanLange `like @searchterm + '%'` produce exactly same query plan as `like Concat(@searchterm,'%')` I don't think it helps.

Comment: I would move this to a stored procedure regardless. When you stick your queries inside the application you are creating an application with no separation of duties. Your application is tightly coupled to your data which is a challenge in a number of ways. Is the data of your parameter the same as your column? I notice your parameter is nvarchar(255). Is your FirstName column the same? Keep in mind that different sizes are considered different datatypes. If not, there is going to be an implicit conversion happening.